# would it be possible for a living creature to have a vacuum organ?

Tags: magic

So in my fantasy world there is a large creature which feeds on berries by sucking them in, would this be possible.

Comment: Hello Sus. Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. If you take a moment to read through the [rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8491/40609) you'll discover you've asked your Q in a way that's out-of-bounds. We help you develop the rules and systems of your fictional world - and, obviously, the creature can exist in your fictional world. We try not to close the questions of new users, but there's not really a question here to answer. What, then, is the specific problem you're trying to solve? What rule of your world are you having trouble developing? Thanks!

Comment: Elephants use their trunk to suck water. Although they then blow it into their mouths, a different system where a creature uses a similar principle to suck a lot of berries and swallow them could be done. One thing you have to keep in mind: make sure some system is in place to deal with sand and dirt being sucked along with it.

Comment: I think the title needs a change, to make the question more clear.. does this beast consist of vacuum (?) or does it have some vacuum organ inside its body, to be able to suck the berries... or does it live IN a vacuum ?

Comment: @Goodies "living vacuum" - probable an American "living vacuum *cleaner*"AKA "a Hoover"

Comment: Ah ok.. I'm not Anglophone, a lot of readers will interpret "vacuum" as a true "vacuum" in the physics sense. I've put an edit proposal.. the title: *"would it be possible for a living creature to have a vacuum organ?"*. In a physical sense,  there is no real vacuum, a vacuum *cleaner* does not contain any vacuum. I'm afraid the answer is trivial: of course, a lot of mammals do it. Create a lower air pressure behind the lips will result in a sucking action. No "vacuum"' - in the physics sense - is needed, the vacuum organ would be the lungs.

Comment: Is this question related to the Eternal Cylinder by any chance?

Comment: Ever use a straw to drink something ?  So, yes, humans can suck things in.

Comment: @Goodies: What you call a lower pressure is generally known as a partial vacuum.

Comment: @AlexP yes.. see previous comment, I acknowledge that. "Vacuum organ" allows both interpretations. When answering assuming the "vacuum cleaner" analogue there would always be a partial vacuum. I upvoted below answer. When requiring a true vacuum in the physics sense, the question  would not be answerable, because a *true* vacuum cannot exist, let alone inside a creature.

Answer (score 3):

### It already exists.

One of the primary functions of the mammalian lung is to create a small vacuum. Although the main usage of this vacuum is to draw in fresh air, it can also be used to do other things.

One of these other functions is to suck in liquid food.

[image: Child sucking on a straw]

While **a traditional mouth is almost always more practical**, sucking in nutrients is certainly viable.

Comment: Don't need lungs to create suction... the shape and musculature of your mouth can do that, without the risk of accidentally inhaling food and giving yourself aspiration pneumonia.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I didn't know that! Of course, it doesn't help that I wasn't born with the proper instincts.